# best approach to deploy dockerized rails app on AWS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, continuous-deployment, docker-machine

I dockerized existing Rails Application and it runs on development properly. I want to deploy the app to production environment. I used docker-compose locally.

Application Stack is as follows:

- Rails app
- Background Workers for mails and cleanup
- Relation DB - `postgres`
- NoSQL DB - `DynamoDB`
- SQS queues
- Action Cable - `Redis`
- Caching - `Memcached`

As far as I know, options for deployment are as below:

- ECS (Trying this, but having difficulties in relating concepts such as Task and Task Definitions with docker-compose concepts)
- ECS with Elastic Beanstalk
- With Docker Machine according to this docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/

I do not have experience with capistrano, haven't used it yet on this project yet so I am not aiming to use it for docker deployment either. I am planning to use some CD/CI solution for easy deployment. I want advice on options available, and how to deploy the stack in a way that is easy to maintain and push updates with minimal deployment efforts?

Comment: I am using `ECS with Elastic Beanstalk` for my stack. There's a fair bit of challenge initially to rewrite your compose file to a Dockerrun.aws.json file but it's really effective & easy once it becomes stable. You may need to change your Dockerfile at times to get Beanstalk support.
ECS is also good but it involves more moving parts as compare to ECS Beanstalk. I don't see docker-machine as a good option if we are on cloud.

Comment: @viveky4d4v will this approach give flexibility to run rake tasks and commands like `rails c` easily? and it would be of great help if you share some tutorial or guide that you found helpful.

Comment: I don't have any tutorials, also the AWS docs are pretty limited as if now. You have to hit and try, i am pretty sure it can't support the exact same compose & Dockerfile in the exact same way. You must be able to run your commands, Dockerrrun.aws.json has entrypoints & commands section. 
Below are few good/essential ref ---
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html
---
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html